# How can i iterate through row of particular table associated with SqlDataSource control in VS 2008?

Tags: sqldatasource

I want to cange the lables in my form according to particular value in rows. I just need how to iterate through table rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SqlDataSource`'s `Select()` method to retrieve data and then you can convert the result into a `DataView` or a `DataReader`.

```
    // Use the result as a DataView.
    var dataview = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    foreach (DataRowView dataviewrow in dataview)
    {
        Label1.Text = dataviewrow["FirstName"].ToString();
    }

    // Use the result as a DataReader.
    var datareader = (SqlDataReader)SqlDataSource2.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    while (datareader.Read())
    {
        Label2.Text = datareader["LastName"].ToString();

    }
    datareader.Close();
```