# Does extracting rows from an SqlDataSource using directcast cause another trip to SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I was looking for a way to extract data from a `SqlDataSource` object within VB.NET code but looking at the code I found for this leads me to believe that the select statement is executed once again during the `DirectCast`.

Does anyone know if this usage causes an additional select statement to be run even though the `SqlDataSource` has already run previously?

The post I got this from is here: [How can i iterate through row of particular table associated with SqlDataSource control in VS 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384709/how-can-i-iterate-through-row-of-particular-table-associated-with-sqldatasource)

Here is the code:

```
Dim datareader = DirectCast(SqlDataSource2.[Select](DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), SqlDataReader)

While datareader.Read()        
     Label2.Text = datareader("LastName").ToString()
End While
datareader.Close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A data reader will read from the source.

If the source is a database, then the reader will read from the database every time you call `Read()`.

It is unclear to me what your [DirectCast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k6y2h6x%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is there for or why you are using it.

Comment: What you say makes sense. I was trying to hook into what I THOUGHT was an already populated datasource on the page (since previously another control had already used the sqldatasource, say on page preload) that way trying to avoid another trip to the database and just use the already loaded data. But from what you say it seems I am indeed going to be making another trip to the DB.

Comment: Upvote it or mark it as an answer to boost your member score.